# Apache beam fileio write compressed files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-io, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I would like to know if it's possible to write compressed files using the fileio module from Apache Beam, Python SDK. At the moment I am using the module to write files to a GCP bucket:

```
_ = (logs | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60*60))
    | 'Convert to JSON' >>  beam.ParDo(ConvertToJson())
    | 'Write logs to GCS file' >> fileio.WriteToFiles(path = gsc_output_path, shards=1, max_writers_per_bundle=0))
```

Compression would help in minimizing storage costs.

According to [this](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/fileio.html#EmptyMatchTreatment) doc and comment inside class _MoveTempFilesIntoFinalDestinationFn, developers still need to implement handling of compression.

Am I right about this or does someone know how to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> developers still need to implement handling of compression.

This is correct.

Though there are open FRs:

- https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/19415
- https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/19941

At the moment, you can write a DoFn: read the final files -> compress -> write the compressed final files and delete original final files.

Comment: Hi ningk, do you have any news about this? In any case, which beam function should I use to compress the original files after reading them?